# How to set the count of a list to one more than the current size of a list c#

Tags: c#, list

Is there a way of setting or changing the size of a list in c# ?

For example if you had a system that added members to a list is there a way of setting a members id to one more than the current size of that list, so that if 3 members were added they would have the id 1 2 and 3 and not 0 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Are you trying to access the members from the list by id?

Comment: Why not just have an Id property on the member?

Comment: you can use vb.net afaik

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do that, but you can always create a new class that inherits from List<T> and implement the indexer the way you want.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz i was thinking of doing it that way but was thinking if there was a way of altering the count of the list.

Comment: Eh.. personally i would just put an Id on the member. Gives you full control of it.

Comment: Add some dummy item to the beginning of the list? That would offset it by 1.

Comment: When you say id, do you mean index? In C# an array/list always start at index 0, should you rearrange items, they would also change index, so if your item needs an id, you should have id property on the item.

Comment: @SystemDown im just thinking of different ways do this thats all just a mess about really thanks for the input though.

Comment: If you want the index to start at something else, or to change the count... The only true way would do as SystemDown said. Extend the List class, here you override every method that returns or get the index and you either plus or subtract 1 to get 1, 2, 3... instead of 0, 1, 2...

Comment: thanks for the input guys think im just making this more complicated than it should be lol ill just stick to what i was gonna do with an id property on member thanks.

Comment: thanks @GalaxyNetworks i might have a look at that

Comment: Remember that the list expects 0, 1, 2... So when you return the index, you should add 1 to get 1, 2, 3... and when you set an index you should subtract 1 to convert back to the list's 0, 1, 2... index...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking?(the class test as a property called id,you change that to your custom type):

```
List<test> t = new List<test>();
t.Add(new test() { id = t.Count + 1 });
t.Add(new test() { id = t.Count + 1 });
t.Add(new test() { id = t.Count + 1 });
```

Comment: yes but i am only replying to OP question,what he does with it its up to him,probably create a method that removes the item and shifts the id property value(above the one he removed) one down...maybe lol.the best i think would be to create a static variable,that everytime he sets the property id it will be the value of that static variable then increment it....but yes your right just like this does not make sense when an item is removed...

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard way of doing this would be to add an ID property to the member.

Then if you have a list like `List<Member>` with an property of type int called `Id` you can use simple LINQ queries to find the objects you want, some examples are below;

```
   // get list of all Id's
   IEnumerable<int> Ids = myList.Select(x => x.Id);
   // get members with Id > than some value
   IEnumerable<Member> members = myList.Where(x => x.Id > MinID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<Member>();

list.Add(new Member(){id=list.Count+1})
```